# create new page (not having the layout specified in /app/layouts/* files) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Most of my view files have the same layouts, hence it was reasonable to define `layouts/application.html.haml` (and other `header`, `footer` files).

But now I need to create a page that does NOT have any of those styling.
In fact, I just want a plain page with a header.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after. In your controller, assuming your action is called myaction

```
    def myaction
      # do here whatever you need to do and then
      render :layout => false
    end
```

See options for render in [Rails Guide: layouts and redendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the layout in the controller like so:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  layout "some_layout"

  # rest of the controller
end
```

This would look for `app/views/layouts/some_layout.html.erb`

You can also use a method to choose the layout:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  layout :choose_layout

  def choose_layout
    current_user.cat? ? "cat" : "dog"
  end
  # rest of the controller
end
```